# StringIndexOutOfBoundException with Substring function Android

Tags: android, substring

I'm getting frustrated with this substring function. Here my substring function giving me value first time only. It has been stored first 3 characters in arraylist. Second time it is not able to take other 3 characters and it has been stored " " value in arralist.

My code is below :

```
 String mStr= "jklpourtujolkjth";

     ArrayList<String> mLst = new ArrayList<String>();

       for (int i = 0; i < mStr.length(); i+=3)

        {
            if ((i + 3) < mStr.length())
            {
                mLst.add(mStr.substring(i,3));
            }
            else{
                mLst.add(mStr.substring(i));

            }
        }
```

Help me with this code. What's wrong with me?

Thanks,

Comment: where and how you've defined mystr?

Comment: @Arash Sorry brother I have edited that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are assuming that `mStr` and `mystr` are the same. Did you mean to use `mStr` in both places? (both in the else block and also in the if block)

Edit (now that that's fixed):

You should use `mStr.substring(i,i+3)` instead of `mStr.substring(i,3)`. Substring takes a starting index and end index, but you are assuming it takes a starting index and length.

Comment: Sorry that was my problem. I have edited that. Check it again!!

Answer (score 0):

```
String mStr= "jklpourtujolkjth";

 ArrayList<String> mLst = new ArrayList<String>();
   for (int i = 0; i < mStr.length(); i+=3)
   {
        int to=i+3;
        if (to < mStr.length())
        {
            mLst.add(String.valueOf(mStr.substring(i,to)));
        }
        else
        {
            mLst.add(mStr.substring(i));
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to give the `endIndex` in the substring method. that's why you are getting outofboundsexception. change your code to like this...

Here the problem is for getting substring in the loop, first time it is calling

```
 mStr.substring(0,3)) which gives the string as jkl
```

next call

```
 mStr.substring(3,3)) which will give outofboundsexception
```

To know more about substring read the doc from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

```
String mStr= "jklpourtujolkjth";

ArrayList<String> mLst = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (int i = 0; i < mStr.length(); i+=3)
  {
       if ((i + 3) < mStr.length())
       {
           mLst.add(String.valueOf(mStr.substring(i,i+3)));// here is the change

       }
       else{
           mLst.add(mStr.substring(i));

       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting exception at 
mLst.add(String.valueOf(mStr.substring(i,3)));

because when i = 6 then what you will get from substring(6,3).
so second parameter should be variable